# JavaFX Change Color of Table Row when Button is clicked

Tags: javafx, tablerow

I want my table to change the color of a row depending on a column is checked or not or when a button is clicked.
I searched for solutions but it never worked the way I wanted to. I am happy for every keyword or help you have. Maybe I was just looking for the wrong thing?

My code looks like this:

```
public class Cellexample_presenter implements Initializable{
@FXML 
TableColumn<ExampleData, Boolean> checkcol;
@FXML 
TableView<ExampleData> testtable;

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

    checkcol.setText("Check");
    ObservableList<ExampleData> exList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    exList.add(new ExampleData(true));
    exList.add(new ExampleData(false));
    
    checkcol.setCellValueFactory(
            new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ExampleData, Boolean>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
                
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(CellDataFeatures<ExampleData, Boolean> param) {
                    return param.getValue().checkProperty();
                }
            });

    testtable.setItems(exList);
    testtable.setEditable(true);
    checkcol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(checkcol));
    
    
}

@FXML
private void clicked() {
    ObservableList<ExampleData> tabledata = testtable.getItems();
    for (ExampleData e : tabledata) {
        System.out.println(e.isCheck());
    }
}
}
```

I found solutions with another `setCellFactory`, but I doesn't seem to work when I already have a `setCellFactory` and I was unable to combine then. Moreover there is still the connection missing to the
change of the `Checkbox`.
Another solution I came across was something with a `PseudoClass` but this also required another `setCellFactory`

The `method private void clicked()` I used to check if the data in my object was really changed.
Also I want as another Feature to click a Button and change the color of rows with wrong data.
I was hoping there was a way to iterate trough the table, check the data and if something doesn't equals something else. It changes color.
Like this in pseudo-code

```
for (tablerow row: table)
     if (row.ischecked()) {
           row.changecolor();
  }
```

Here is the .FXML for putting everything together:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
 <?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
 <?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

 <AnchorPane prefHeight="254.0" prefWidth="700.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" 
  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
  fx:controller="pathToFXML/Cellexample_presenter">
  <children>
  <Pane layoutX="-269.0" prefHeight="315.0" prefWidth="700.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" 
  AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
     <children>
        <TableView fx:id="testtable" layoutX="142.0" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="200.0" 
       prefWidth="340.0">
          <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="checkcol" prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
          </columns>
        </TableView>
        <Button fx:id="checkbtn" layoutX="70.0" layoutY="36.0" mnemonicParsing="false" 
     onAction="#clicked" text="isChecked" />
     </children>
     </Pane>
   </children>
  </AnchorPane>
```

Comment: don't see you doing anything to change the color .. follow the examples you (said) found ;) come back with an [mcve] demonstrating how they don't work as expected. And no: looping through rows is the completely wrong approach (rows are virtualized, implying they are re-used!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom `TableRow` for this. I also prefer to use CSS and `PseudoClass`es to manage the color of rows.

What needs to happen here is that the row needs to know if the `checked` property in the `ExampleData` instance currently displayed by the row changes, and needs to change color if that happens.

Of course, for any given table row, the `ExampleData` instance displayed by that table row may also change (e.g. if the underlying data list changes, or if the user scrolls the table, etc.)

So the basic strategy here is:

1. Create a listener that observes the current item's `checked` property, and updates the pseudoclass state if it does (which in turn causes the style to change). In the code below I call this listener `checkListener`.
2. If the item displayed by the row changes, we need to stop observing the old item's `checked` property and start observing the new item's `checked` property instead. This can be achieved via a listener on the `item` property of the table row. That listener on the `itemProperty` can then remove the `checkListener` from the `checkedProperty` of the old item (if there was an old item), and add it to the `checkedProperty` of the new item (if there is one). It also needs to update the pseudoclass state according to the current state of the new item's `checkedProperty`.

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

    // Existing code....

    testTable.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<ExampleData>() {

        private final PseudoClass checkedPC = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("checked");

        private final ChangeListener<Boolean> checkListener = (obs, wasChecked, isNowChecked) -> 
            pseudoClassStateChanged(checkedPC, isNowChecked);

        {
             itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
                 if (oldItem != null) {
                     oldItem.checkedProperty().removeListener(checkListener);
                 }
                 if (newItem == null) {
                     pseudoClassStateChanged(checkedPC, false);
                 } else {
                     pseudoClassStateChanged(checkedPC, newItem.isChecked());
                     newItem.checkedProperty().addListener(checkListener);
                 }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And then in your external CSS file include

```css
.table-row-cell:checked {
    -fx-background-color: red ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked just fine. Just for understanding the Code, the ChangeListener ist Listening to the column, while the SecondListener, which is added to the itemProperty refers to the TableRow? So I am adding the checklistener to the Tablerow? And remove and add listener is nesseccary because the rowFactory always makes new Items?

Comment: @GrimSqueaker No, that's not really correct (and it looks like you need to review how table views work). I'll added some explanation to the answer.

Comment: _and it looks like you need to review how table views work_ exactly ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! And will do! I have still a lot to learn and I feel like these factories and callbacks are still hard for me to understand.